# Can I convert a string into a list[int] in flask/python?

Tags: python, flask

This is what the string looks like:

```
 dataString = "[100, 200, 300, 400, 500]"
```

This is what I want to convert into:

```
 dataConverted = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your string is follows JSON format, so you can use `json.loads`

```
import json
dataString = "[100, 200, 300, 400, 500]"
dataConverted = json.loads(dataString)
print(dataConverted) # [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Ill try your solution, I'll comeback later

Answer (score 0):

```
dataString = "[100, 200, 300, 400, 500]"
from ast import literal_eval

data = literal_eval(dataString)
print(data)
print(type(data))

//[100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
//<class 'list'>
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I'll try your solution, Ill come back later.

Answer (score 0):

```
list_str = "[100, 200, 300, 400, 500]"

# split by using ',' 
items = list_str.split(",")

new_list = []

# add items to new list
for item in items:
  new_list.append(int(item.replace("[", "").replace("]", "")))

print(new_list)
```

Comment: The 2 other solutions are way better, but let's improve yours. The bracket are here only once so don't apply the replace in the loop, but here with `str.strip` `items = list_str.strip("[]").split(",")`

Comment: Thanks azro you are right, the strip is more efficent.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).